# What is the formal problem caused by interpreting dx as an infinitesimal?

Tags: calculus

My mother is a physicist. One evening, I told her $dx$ is a linear mapp $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ taking $\hat u_x=e_1$ to 1 and the other canonical vectors to 0 (if considered on $\mathbb{R}^3$). She answered, «but why do you have to make it so complicated, come on, $dx$ is the infinitesimal step in the $x$ direction!». I'm sure such an interpretation formally makes no sense, but could you explain why? I mean, what problem comes about with that interpretation of $dx$?

PS I have seen a post about this but I have no time to read all of that, so could you please give me a simple argument to answer my mum with :)?

Comment: Ask your mum to define an "infinitesimal". Also read [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-dy-dx-not-a-ratio/21209#21209).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Archimedean Property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) forbids the existence of infinitesimal values. It states:
$$
(\forall x > 0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})\left( \frac{1}{N} < x \right).
$$

If $ x $ is an infinitesimal, then the above statement isn’t true. Hence, if you want the Archimedean Property to hold, then you can’t have infinitesimals. Note that the Archimedean Property is a characteristic property of $ \mathbb{R} $, being one of the axioms of the real-number system.

**Note:** There are real-number systems with infinitesimals. Have a look at [non-standard analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) with the set of [hyperreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number). It’s thus possible to have infinitesimals, and there are no formal problem with them. However, you’ll lose the Archimedean Property once you impose the existence of infinitesimals...